# How to Test Google Play Billing Subscription(Not In-App Purchase) in android

Tags: android-studio, google-play-console, billing, android-billing

I have implemented Google Play Billing Subscription (Monthly) and the app is live on Google Play. How can I test the subscription is working fine or not. When I run Subscription code it asks for a payment method.

Comment: Tangential - you can also automate this https://youtu.be/wC7gBUfvZNU?si=Cr1yKPgYMXMvLYa_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the dashboard of your application in Google Play Console, From the left side Select Settings > License Testing and add emails of the testers. Please see below attached image. Make sur the selected subscription is Active.

[image]

Comment: Why I need to change the License Response as Licensed. Does it make any issues?

Comment: @sejn You can try both :-)

Comment: Does the Licenced one make me to pay the bill

Comment: Yes, the testers above will behave as like they have purchased the real product but will not e charged form account.

Comment: I have tried to add the email, but it not showed my email in the testers list after giving the save option

Comment: I have a question as well, before adding the testers shall i need to create internal testing and add the build inside that?

Comment: Can you plz share the Screen shot of where you have added Testers.

Comment: Thanks. I can able to add the testers. But if i use the payment it shows the cancellation message after 5 mins.  If I buy the product does the test card works same like the payed one. It shows cancellaton message as well in the gmail

Comment: Can I repeat the testing with the same with the same. Note: I can't able to see the declined card in the app